# How could I solve the error "Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist" using UserDefinedFunction over a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to define a UseDefinedFunction in Pyspark to work over a dataframe's instances values in order to generate a new attribute based on those values.

I have a code like this:

```
# I have a global attribute named 'global_dataframe' which is a dataframe containing some interesant instances.

from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction


def method1(instance, list_attribute_names):

    if(instance['Att1'] != '-'):
        return instance['Att1']
    else:
        i = 0
        result = "-"
        query_SQL = ""
        while(i < len(list_attribute_names)):
            atr_imp = lista_2[i]
            query_SQL = query_SQL + atr_imp + " = '" + instance[atr_imp] + "',"
            i = i + 1
        query_SQL = query_SQL[:-1]

        # Here I filter the global_dataframe to get the results which are interesting according to the query generated before with the values of the instance passed to the method as a parameter
        result_df = global_dataframe.filter(query_SQL)
        if(result_df.head() != None):# If dataframe is empty
            result = "None"
        else:
            result = query_SQL
        return result

def method0(df, important_attributes):


    udf_func = UserDefinedFunction(lambda instance: method1(instance, important_attributes), StringType())
    column = udf_func(df)


    df = df.withColumnRenamed("Att1", column)
    return df
```

When I execute this line:

```
example = method0(dataframe_example, attribute_list_example)
```

I get the next error:

```
y4JError: An error occurred while calling o710.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
at 
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at 
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The idea with this code is to execute method0 over a dataframe and depending on their attribute values, get another column.

How could I do this solving the error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are trying to serialize the global variable `global_dataframe`. The executors should not try to call operations on a DataFrame - this doesn't make any sense. The scope of the executors is to operate on **individual rows** of a DataFrame (or RDD) only.

You can resolve this by evaluating if `global_dataframe` is empty beforehand and passing an argument `is_empty` to the method `method1`.

Comment: So, you suggest to pass an argument     is_empty to ensure that the dataframe is or not empty?

Comment: So, is there any chance to pass an instance of a dataframe in a lambda function to a UDF, and check in that function the value of the different attributes of that instance?

Comment: No, there is no way to pass a `DataFrame` to a UDF. The UDF should only operate on a single data point, not the whole data set. The key point is that you cannot call functions on an `DataFrame` or `RDD` from within a function that is executed by an executor.

Comment: As long as you remove all references to `global_dataframe` from `method1`, the problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, how could I generate a new column taking in account some attributes of the dataframe to be analyzed?

Comment: You should just be able to use `DataFrame.withColumn` for most transformations. Here's an example usage from the [pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types): `df = df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2)`